# How to install lcov tool in Windows machine for flutter code coverage

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, code-coverage, test-coverage, lcov

How to install lcov tool in Windows machine so that I can use the genhtml command to generate html files for my code coverage output files?

I generated code coverage for my flutter app. The file type is lcov.info. I need to make this file readable like html files.

Please anyone tell me the proper steps to install lcov in Windows machine.i have tried many ways to install lcov but nothing works.